# Inserting Sparse data into Oracle table

Tags: oracle, insert

There is a lot of Columns in a table. For example, there are 10 columns, and not many columns to use(sparse).Only columns 2 and 7 contain data, all other columns are NULL.

I have tried to "insert into" like below.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEU (  
  R1 VARCHAR(15),    
  R2 VARCHAR(15),    
  R3 VARCHAR(15),    
  R4 VARCHAR(15),    
  R5 VARCHAR(15),    
  R6 VARCHAR(15),    
  R7 VARCHAR(15),    
  R8 VARCHAR(15),    
  R9 VARCHAR(15),    
  R10 VARCHAR(15) 
  );
 INSERT INTO TABLEU VALUES(NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Is there any other way than the one above?
(Because there are many columns, it is easy to confuse the order of the columns, 
had to designate the rest of each columns NULL.※I am not allowed to alter table.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and safest way is to list the columns you want to populate:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEU (r2, r7) VALUES (20, 70);
```

The other columns will be populated with NULL (or the default value if the column has one).